# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el primer día la semana en mi calendario sea Lunes y no Domingo?

Tags: javascript, date

Esta es mi primer pregunta y disculpen si no se formula bien, intentaré darme a entender conforme salgan preguntas.

Tengo el siguiente código javascript:

```js
//Esto es el inicio:
let meses_array=['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'];
let dias_array=['L','M','M','J','V','S','D'];

let contenedor=$('.container');

//Aquí se crea parte de la tabla según los arrays para los meses.
for(let x=0; x<meses_array.length; x++){

    contenedor.append(
        '<div class="mes">'+
            '<table class="tabla_meses">'+
                '<caption>'+
                    meses_array[x]+
                '</caption>'+
                '<thead>'+
                    '<tr>'+
                        '<th></th>'+
                    '</tr>'+
                '</thead>'+
                '<tbody>'+
                    '<tr>'+
                        '<td></td>'+
                    '</tr>'+
                '</tbody>'+
            '</table>'+
        '</div>'
    );

}

//Aquí se crean la tablas que en sí contienen los dias y van numerados por semana de forma horizontal.

for(let x=0; x<dias_array.length; x++){

    $('.tabla_meses thead tr').append(
        '<th>'+
            dias_array[x]+
        '</th>'
    );

}

for(let x=0; x<6; x++){

    $('.tabla_meses tbody').append(
        '<tr class="num_semana">'+
            '<td>'+
                parseInt(x+1)+
            '</td>'+
        '</tr>'
    );

}

for(let x=0; x<7; x++){

    $('.tabla_meses tbody tr').append(
        '<td></td>'
    );

}


for(let x=1; x<366; x++){

    let fecha=establecer_fecha(2019, x);
    let mes=fecha.getMonth();
    let num_dia=fecha.getDate();
    let dia_semana=fecha.getDay()+1;
    let tabla_select=$('.tabla_meses')[mes];

    if(num_dia===1){
        var semana=1;
    }



tabla_select.children[2].children[semana].children[dia_semana].innerText=num_dia;

    if(dia_semana===7){
        semana=semana+1;
    }

}

function establecer_fecha(year, mes){
    let fecha=new Date(year, 0);
    return new Date(fecha.setDate(mes));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

</div>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que el primer día la semana en el calendario sea Lunes y no Domingo?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! usa el boton [edit] y aclara donde esta el problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para resolverlo debes rotar los valores del día de la semana cambiando esta linea:

```
let dia_semana=fecha.getDay()+1;
```

por esta:

```
let dia_semana=(6+fecha.getDay())%7+1;
```

**Explicación:** `fecha.getDay()` retorna el numero de día (de domingo a sábado) entre 0 a 6, para acomodarlo en tu tabla le sumas uno quedando los valores de 1 a 7.

Para cambiar el primer día de la semana como lunes en lugar de domingo le sumas 6 a `fecha.getDay()`, lo que hace que el domingo sea el 6 y no el 0, luego aplicas modulo 7, para restarle 7 a los demás días quedando lunes como el primer día (0).

Por ultimo le sumas 1 para agregarlo a tu tabla.

```js
//Esto es el inicio:
let meses_array=['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'];
let dias_array=['L','M','M','J','V','S','D'];

let contenedor=$('.container');

//Aquí se crea parte de la tabla según los arrays para los meses.
for(let x=0; x<meses_array.length; x++){

    contenedor.append(
        '<div class="mes">'+
            '<table class="tabla_meses">'+
                '<caption>'+
                    meses_array[x]+
                '</caption>'+
                '<thead>'+
                    '<tr>'+
                        '<th></th>'+
                    '</tr>'+
                '</thead>'+
                '<tbody>'+
                    '<tr>'+
                        '<td></td>'+
                    '</tr>'+
                '</tbody>'+
            '</table>'+
        '</div>'
    );

}

//Aquí se crean la tablas que en sí contienen los dias y van numerados por semana de forma horizontal.

for(let x=0; x<dias_array.length; x++){

    $('.tabla_meses thead tr').append(
        '<th>'+
            dias_array[x]+
        '</th>'
    );

}

for(let x=0; x<6; x++){

    $('.tabla_meses tbody').append(
        '<tr class="num_semana">'+
            '<td>'+
                parseInt(x+1)+
            '</td>'+
        '</tr>'
    );

}

for(let x=0; x<7; x++){

    $('.tabla_meses tbody tr').append(
        '<td></td>'
    );

}


for(let x=1; x<366; x++){

    let fecha=establecer_fecha(2019, x);
    let mes=fecha.getMonth();
    let num_dia=fecha.getDate();
    let dia_semana=(6+fecha.getDay())%7+1;
    let tabla_select=$('.tabla_meses')[mes];

    if(num_dia===1){
        var semana=1;
    }

tabla_select.children[2].children[semana].children[dia_semana].innerText=num_dia;

    if(dia_semana===7){
        semana=semana+1;
    }

}

function establecer_fecha(year, mes){
    let fecha=new Date(year, 0);
    return new Date(fecha.setDate(mes));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Y de esa forma el calendario ya esta correcto, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias the-breaker, tu respuesta dio solución a lo que buscaba; eres un genio amigo.

Comment: @FabioJ543 de nada, que tengas buen día.